# angularjs with nw.js not working. ng-src attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nw.js

problem with the ng-src attribute.
I run the project on localhost in the pictures are displayed correctly.

```
<img width = "100%" ng-src = "{{item.poster}}">
```

But if I start the project using the nw.js, there are no pictute but only text values.
Who was faced with this problem. Tell me how to solve.

Here is the entire code of the code which I repeat

```
<div class="col-md-2 movie-con" style="padding:5px" ng-repeat="item in movie | filter:query">
    <div class="col-md-12 img" style="padding:0;">
        <img width="100%" ng-src="{{ item.poster }}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span style="color:#AEAEAE;">{{ item.name }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share how it looks like on nw.js?

Comment: Maybe investigate the actual addresses and confirm they are pointing to the right resource location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|chrome-extension):/);
}]);
```

This solves the problem with displaying images. I helped

Answer (score 1):

You can use directive "ng-if". Here is example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" style="border: 1px solid blue; margin: 10px; display: inline-box;" >
      <div ng-if="!item.url">
        {{item.title}}
      </div>

      <div ng-if="item.url">
        <img src="{{item.url}}" height=80 />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is live example: http://jsfiddle.net/4bstcobj/1/